# can't read file c++

Tags: c++

There is a file in directory and i'm trying to read a file but i can't. What is wrong with my code. Example is taken from http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/37208/

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#define MAX_LEN 100
using namespace std;
string inlasning ()
{
  string text;
  string temp; // Added this line

  ifstream file;
  file.open ("D:\education\Third course\semestr 2\security\lab1.2\secret_msg.txt");

  while (!file.eof())
  {
    getline (file, temp);
    text.append (temp); // Added this line
  }


  cout << "THE FILE, FOR TESTING:\n" // For testing
       << text << "\n";

  file.close();

  return text;
}
void main ()
{
inlasning();
}
```

Comment: Remember that \ in a string makes whatever follows it "special"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `\` to `\\` in file path. (or to `/`)

Comment: OP did not say if he/she is working with Windows/Linux/Mac. Does "/" work everywhere?

Comment: Ah yes, but I am curious, does forward slash ("/") work in Windows? I remember it did not work when I had tried the same long back...

Comment: Forward slash in path works on windows, I just checked it in Codeblock IDE 10.05

Answer (score 1):

In string literals `\` is used as an escape character.

You have to write `\\`.

Note: you should check the `open` call.

> On failure, the failbit flag is set (which can be checked with member
>   fail), and depending on the value set with exceptions an exception may
>   be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character, so you need to use `\\` to obtain the result you intend.
This is true almost everywhere, even here in stackoverflow where you nee to use it in order to write something like this for example:

*A*

(just put the `\` before the `*`), otherwise (if you don't use the `\`) stackoverflow will interpret the text and will output an italic A, this:

*A*

The same is true for bold (two asterisks... two slashes):

**A**

instead of

**A**

:)

... **or maybe you cannot read it because it is a "secret_msg"** :P (LOL)